# In highcharts how can I provide data with values x, y, title so that I can put the title in the tooltip?

Tags: highcharts

Initially I did this:

```
var highchartData = [];

<start loop>
var miniArray = [];
miniArray.push(result[i].NumberOfKittens);
miniArray.push(result[i].TimeOfBirth);
highchartData.push(miniArray);
<end loop>

$('#highchart').highcharts().addSeries({
    name: "Kittens born",
    data: highchartData
});
```

However in my tooltip I want the name of the mummy kitten, so I want to include it. I tried replacing the loop with this:

```
var myItem = {
    NumberOfKittens: result[i].NumberOfKittens,
    TimeOfBirth: result[i].TimeOfBirth,
    MummyKittenName: result[i].MummyKittenName
};

highchartData.push(myItem);
```

But I just got an error saying `Highcharts expects point configuration to be numbers or arrays in turbo mode`.

I guess I need to tell it which values on the json to use as X and Y but I can't figure out how from the documentation. Any ideas? Ultimately I just want a tooltip that plots a point at X,Y and can display additional info in the tooltip, but as I could only get it to work passing X,Y I couldn't add metadata to each record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts expects a certain structure for the values/names in a point.

See [series.data](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cline%3E.data) in the API where you can find the following structure:

```
data: [{
    x: 1,
    y: 10,
    name: "Point2",
    color: "#00FF00"
}, {
   x: 1,
   y: 6,
   name: "Point1",
   color: "#FF00FF"
}]
```

So if you change your point buildup to:

```
var myItem = {
    y: result[i].NumberOfKittens,
    x: result[i].TimeOfBirth,
    name: result[i].MummyKittenName
};

highchartData.push(myItem);
```

It should work.

Then you will need to format the tooltip to your liking, see [Highcharts API on tooltips](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter).
Where this is the key takeaway:

> this.point (not shared) / this.points[i].point (shared)
>
> The point object. The point name, if defined, is available through **this.point.name.**

The above is valid for a line graph and most other graphs, however, some graphs take different options for the points.

Comment: Thanks, I see - I thought I could use custom data rather than having to use the specific 'name' attribute. I am getting closer to having it work. It works if I reduce the number of records suggesting one of them has an invalid value or something, although it worked fine with the same data before I tried to incorporate name. However `point.name` is blank in the tooltip, even though I am setting it in the json data. this.point.name gives an error

Comment: First problem solved, removed the default limit of 1000 points. Just need to figure out why the point name isn't coming up in the tooltip.

Comment: Are you using `point.name` or `this.point.name`? Because you need to be using `this.point.name`.

See working example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kut8v6hk/).

Comment: On the tooltip, instead of `point.name` I used `point.key` and it works. Something to do with scatter charts using a different tooltip layout or something. Even though I set the data by specifying `name`. Thanks for your help.